# How to Setup SSL on Tomee

Tags: tomcat, ssl, lets-encrypt, apache-tomee

I'm trying to setup SSL for an Tomee Server. So far, I tryed to use letsencrypt and followed this https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html.

And while https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest says everything is more or less fine (i.e. lets encrypt as a authority).

However, when I test my browser, Chrome it displays:

> Site security certificate is not trusted!
>   NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

(same problem in Firefox and Opera)

Does know how to fix that? I appreciate if anyone can point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The certificate you used is not signed by a certificate authority. Typically for development it's ok to use a self-signed certificate, but production website should absolutely be signed by a CA.